# bind a store to a list filter in extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, binding, viewmodel, store

I am using extjs 5 on web app using sencha CMD layout (mvvm) and would like to bind a store (for labels) to filter list in my view grid
the viewModel store definition is:

```
 stores: {
    labelContacts: {
        model: 'myapp.model.label.Contact'
        , autoLoad: true
    } // end contact store
 } // end stores
```

and my list filter code in view grid

```
filter: {
                type: 'list',
                bind: {store: '{labelContacts}'}
                labelField: 'DisplayValue',
                valueField: 'keyId'
        }
```

the filter works but it doesn't show data from the bound store but creates it's own from the grid's store

am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to get the bound store but I am not satisfied by the solution as it's not really an elegant one, and would be glad to hear any suggestions
my solution was changing the store to:

```
filter: {
    type: 'list',
    store:new myapp.view.main.MainModel().getStore('labelContacts'),
    labelField: 'label',
    valueField: 'id'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass these property in filter and try this:

```
        type: 'list',
        store: store, // your store
        labelField: 'DisplayValue', // Your displayValue
        valueField: 'keyId', // Key Id on which you want to add filter
```

Comment: I am aware of the config of a simple filter, what I am trying to do here is using a bound store from the viewModel

Answer (score 0):

Another method, works for me

```
        {
            text: 'Yes/No',
            dataIndex: 'accompanied',
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
            },
            listeners: {
                boxready: function (_this, width, height, eOpts) {
                    _this.filter.store = _this.lookupViewModel().getStore('dicYesNo');
                }
            }
        }
```